# How to sorting collection in magento by newest first and out of stock last in same collection

Tags: magento-1.8, event-observer, product-collection

i need to sorting collection in two way in one collection.
first i need to sort new product on top.
out of stock product in last.

basically i need this solution by observer.
I used this ...

### my config...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Nine_Catalog>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Nine_Catalog>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <events>
            <catalog_block_product_list_collection>
                <observers>
                    <filter_blank_image> // unique idrntifer
                     <type>model</type>
                        <class>Nine_Catalog_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>filterBlankImage</method>
                    </filter_blank_image>
                </observers>
            </catalog_block_product_list_collection>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

### my observer

```
class Nine_Catalog_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer{

public function filterBlankImage(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();


   $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                array('_inventory_table' => $collection->getTable('cataloginventory/stock_item')),
                "_inventory_table.product_id = e.entity_id",
                array('is_in_stock')
            )
            ->order('is_in_stock DESC')
            ->order('created_at DESC');
}

}

}
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly you are trying to do something in one query but it can't be done. Please read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sorting-rows.html . If you are using `ORDER BY created_at, is_in_stock` and if there are some rows with same created_at date then it will be used is_in_stock to sort only these rows. You have to combine 2 collections or maybe to use UNION.

Comment: Your observer seems to work fine for me - what is the actual issue you're seeing? when I run the same code, I get new products first, out of stock products last.

Comment: @dkstack can you update us on your issue? Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes what exact problem do you have? What does your code produce. Besides a syntax error (too many closing braces at the end) I cannot see an issue with it.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you need this in an observer? Heres what I did that might put you on the right path:

Extend **Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection** to overwrite **function addAttributeToSort**

Just below

`$storeId = $this->getStoreId();`

Add the following:

`$this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
array('_inventory_table'=>$this->getTable('cataloginventory/stock_item')),
    "_inventory_table.product_id = e.entity_id", 
    array('is_in_stock', 'manage_stock'));

$this->addExpressionAttributeToSelect(
    'on_top',
    '(CASE WHEN (((_inventory_table.use_config_manage_stock = 1) 
    AND (_inventory_table.is_in_stock = 1))
    OR  ((_inventory_table.use_config_manage_stock = 0) 
    AND (1 - _inventory_table.manage_stock + _inventory_table.is_in_stock >= 1))) 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)',
    array());
$this->getSelect()->order('on_top DESC');`

This will put out of stock products at the end of any product collection. If you call addAttributeToSort('created_at','DESC') on your collection it will sort by created_at but move out of stock products to the end of the collection. Same with any other attribute.

Full Module at [`github`](https://github.com/devamitbera/magento-stackexchange/tree/master/49062/app)